# Using gdalwarp to extract same dimension thumbnails of cities

Tags: gdal

I have a georeferenced tiff of Europe and I would like to extract thumbnails of cities, with the same size and GSD.

Say the inputs are.

- 48.8566 N, 2.3522 E for Paris
- 100km x 100km extent
- 1km GSD

What gdalwarp command will result in a 100x100 pixel thumbnail of Paris?

Answer (score 0):

As it's not mentioned, I will consider the SRS as EPSG:4326. At the scale of the Europe, you won't have the same resolution depending on the latitude.

First, let's compute the boundaries of a square (approximated) of side `d` in km centered on a specific coordinate.

```
degree_to_rad(r):
  return r * 2 * PI / 360

delta_latitude  = d / (degree_to_rad(1) * 6370)
delta_longitude = delta_latitude / cosinus(degree_to_rad(lat))

xmin = lng - delta_longitude/2
xmax = lng + delta_longitude/2
ymin = lat - delta_latitude/2
ymax = lat + delta_latitude/2
```

This gives for `lat=48.8566`, `lng=2.3522`:

```
xmin = 1.6686613990086685
xmax = 3.035738600991331
ymin = 48.406868606647706
ymax = 49.306331393352295
```

Now using the `te` option of gdalwrap https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te:

```
gdalwrap -te 1.6686613990086685 48.406868606647706 3.035738600991331 49.306331393352295 input.tif output.tif
```

You will have the same resolution of your original tiff.

Comment: Thanks, but not really what I was looking for. If I had wanted to stay in the SRS of the original image, I could have used gdal_translate. This will not help me extract images with the same scale, size and aspect ratio of different cities.